# Tridion Web8.5 Token Service Not working

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, sites-9

I've setup discovery service and disabled the OAuth, when I run the discovery service it works fine. But when I try to run the token service, it doesn't return anything. Please help. 
How do I find the clientId and ClientSecret for token service?

Comment: You can refer to this article https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/2017/09/02/using-postman-to-explore-sdl-restful-microservices/ and test with the postman to see it's getting the access toekn, check discovery service Is there any error message ub core.log file? and update the error logs details in the questions.

Comment: How exactly do you "try to run the token service"? Are you posting anything to it?
You can set the client ID and secret in the configuration file for the Discovery Service.